Why can't I get Google Sheets to display this info as a pie chart?
I am so, so frustrated right now. I imagine it's because I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. I have a decent amount of experience with Google Sheets and I've never had this problem before.
I'm trying to get Google Sheets to display the following info in a pie chart, displaying each number as a percent thereof.
Data
But what it really, really wants to do, is only display how much each row in column A makes up column A, which is of course 14.3% each.
The chart I do not want I know this already, I do not need a chart for it. The range is set to include Column B, but it is not included in the pie chart whatsoever.
How do I make this work? I have a deadline to meet and I've eaten up 30 minutes trying in vain to make the damn pie chart.

Also, sorry for the weird image inserts, this is my first post so I didn't know how it would look.


Set Column_A to Label and Column_B to Value within the pie chart settings

